# How to create two sub screens such that one one view changes when the user clicks the button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am struck with this thing.. Dont know how to implement this one...
My requirement is When..user clicks on the second half of the screen.., Only the second half of the screen should change, So.., modalViewController and pushViewController wont help I guess..,
The first half of the screens remains fixed. Depending on the control logic, I can then navigate to the next respective second half screen and the first part of the screen remains fixed

Answer (score 1):

Add two subview to your view and listen for touches (touchesBegan:withEvent:) on them in your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own split view controller which mimics a navigation controller but manages its own views. Have a sub view for the bottom part and animate changes / navigation from this controller.